# Convert basic query to eloquent orm laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm converting some project from pure PHP to Laravel 4, and I have a problem with converting this query

```
Select * FROM as_secrets WHERE approved = 1 ORDER BY (likes+dislikes) desc
```

to Eloquent ORM. Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$result = AsSecret::where('approved', 1)->orderBy(\DB::raw('(likes+dislikes) DESC')->get();`